# Php Destructor Is being call twice

Tags: php, mysql

I searched alot and found alots of question similar to mine but no where I founded my awnser so Im asking here.

I have the following code.

```
class Checkout
{
static $dbCon = null;
private $CheckoutId = null;

public function __construct()
{
    echo"Contructor";
//       Check if have an checkout already
    $Prepare = Checkout::$dbCon ->prepare("SELECT * FROM checkouts WHERE SessionId = :SessionId AND LastTouchTime >= :Time ORDER BY Id DESC");
    $Prepare -> bindValue(':SessionId',session_id());
    $Prepare -> bindValue(':Time',0); // Will be something like time()-(60*60*2)
    try{
        $Prepare -> execute();
        if($Prepare -> rowCount() != 0)
        {
            $Checkout = $Prepare->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $ThisVar = unserialize($Checkout['ObjectSerialized']);
            foreach($ThisVar as $Key => $Val)
                $this->$Key = $Val;
            $this->CheckoutId = $Checkout['Id'];
            echo " -> $this->CheckoutId\n";
        }
    }catch(PDOException $e)
    { die("Error Getting checkout From Db: ".$e->getMessage()); }
}
public function __destruct()
{
    echo "Destructor -> ".(is_null($this->CheckoutId)?'Null':$this->CheckoutId)."\n";
    if(is_null($this->CheckoutId))
    {// Insert Checkout In db
            $InsertCheckout = Checkout::$dbCon->prepare("INSERT INTO checkouts (`SessionId`,`LastTouchTime`,`ObjectSerialized`) VALUES(:SessionId,:LastTouchTime,:ObjectSer);");
            $InsertCheckout -> bindValue(':SessionId',session_id());
            $InsertCheckout -> bindValue(':LastTouchTime',time());
            $InsertCheckout -> bindValue(':ObjectSer',serialize($this));
            try{
                $InsertCheckout -> execute();
                echo "Just Inserted Checkout\n";
            }catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                die("Error SavingCart In Db: ".$e->getMessage());
            }
    }
    else
    {
        //$UpdateCheckout = Checkout::$dbCon->prepare("");
    }
}
}
```

And I init this class like the following

```
Checkout::$dbCon = new $PDOObject; ( is valid )
$Checkout = new Checkout();
```

What I get as result is something prety wierd.

```
Contructor -> 142
Destructor -> Null
Just Inserted Checkout
Destructor -> 142
```

You see Here if the contruct echo me an number this mean that the number is in $this->$CheckoutId

But then the destructor run and there is no number in $CheckoutId so it re-insert an new record.

then the destructor run again and ops This time he have an number so it will try to update the record instead.

Is there something that im missing??

**Edit**
If I Comment the line `$ThisVar = unserialize($Checkout['ObjectSerialized']);`
It does not run the destruct for no reason.

Why ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455103/what-makes-destruct-called-twice-in-such-a-simple-php-code    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201342/php-destruct-called-twice

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8461394/1320305

Comment: Thanks for the constructive comment, But I already had a look at that question yesterday and at that point I did try to remove this setting and it still persist :/

Comment: I just realize that when I comment Out the line $ThisVar = unserialize($Checkout['ObjectSerialized']); It work as expected! ?